# EF core Memory leak in multithreaded console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-leaks, entity-framework-core, autofac

I created a small console application, where I am simulating a memory leak issue I have using EF core in an Azure Service Bus messaging application.

The setup is as follows:

I inherit from DbContext in MyContext

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly Assembly configurationAssembly;

    public MyContext(Assembly configurationAssembly, DbContextOptions dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
        this.configurationAssembly = configurationAssembly;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(this.configurationAssembly);
    }
}
```

I have a POCO class:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Applicationcode { get; set; }
}
```

And an EntityTypeConfiguration:

```
public class JobConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Job>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Job> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Job_OP");
    }
}
```

MyContext uses this configuration in the OnModelCreating override (ApplyConfigurationFromAssembly)

Finally in Program I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    private static IContainer container;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); //Autofac dependency injection

        var dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestEFThreads;Integrated Security=True");

        builder.Register(ctx => new MyContext(
            Assembly.Load("TestEFThreads"),
            dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options));
        //I tried to use different lifetime scopes here, but EF doesn't like using the same dbContext concurrently in different threads.
        //Currently each resolve instantiates a new MyContext

        container = builder.Build();

        var input = ShowMenu();
        var nrOfSimulatedMessages = 0;
        while (!string.Equals(input, "q", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            try
            {
                nrOfSimulatedMessages = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                PerformSimulation(maxThreads: 10, nrOfSimulatedMessages);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Incorrect input or exception, {e}");
            }
            input = ShowMenu().ToLower();
        }
    }

    static string ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of simulated messages or q to quit");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PerformSimulation(int maxThreads, int nrOfSimulatedMessages)
    {
        var messageCount = 0;

        var tasks = new Task[maxThreads];

        while (messageCount < nrOfSimulatedMessages)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads && messageCount < nrOfSimulatedMessages; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Creating thread {i} for message {messageCount}");
                tasks[i] = new Task(StartProcessing);
                tasks[i].Start();
                messageCount++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for all threads to finish");
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.Where(a=>a !=null).ToArray());
        }
    }

    private static void StartProcessing()
    {
        using (var lifeTime = container.BeginLifetimeScope()) //does not help
        {
            var myContext = container.Resolve<MyContext>();
            var job = myContext.Set<Job>().SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == 1);
            Console.WriteLine($"Found job with applicationCode {job.Applicationcode}");
            myContext.Dispose(); //memory leak even with dispose
        }
    }
}
```

So this application does a simple read from a db, and does so a specified number of times, each in a separate thread.

When I run it for about 50000 'messages' the memory keeps increasing as can be seen in the diagnostics.
It does not seem to be garbage collected.

[image: Diagnostics]

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this memory leak?

Update:
It seems to be related to the Autofac dependency injection.
If I just use new MyContext iso resolving it memory usage is fine.

```
    private static void StartProcessing()
    {
        var myContext = new MyContext(Assembly.Load("TestEFThreads"), dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);

        var job = myContext.Set<Job>().SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == 1);
        Console.WriteLine($"Found job with applicationCode {job.Applicationcode}");
    }
```

I do need to use dependency injection however.

Comment: It's not necessarily a memory leak.  Garbage collection can wait for quite some time to reclaim memory, if there's no memory pressure from other programs or system processes.

Comment: Hi, the application ends up using almost 4GB of memory so  I do think its a problem. Also the yellow markers in the diagnostics indicates the start of a managed heap garbage collection so I would expect it to drop there.

Comment: Are you using `using` statements?  I don't see any `using` statements on your DbContext objects.  The only `using` statement I see is on that `BeginLifetimeScope()` call, and that has to do with autofac.  `DbContext` objects have their own lifetime management, and unless you plan on figuring out a way to change out that DbContext for some other technology, injecting it seems pointless.

Comment: Also, are your sure that the returned job object isn't null ? By design, autofac holds references on disposable objects and if the call to Console.Writeline was to fail in your code, the DbContext would never be disposed. Could you try again with a using statement as suggested above ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I wrapped Container.Resolve<MyContext> in a using statement but it doesn't help. The job oject isn't null and I can see the output of Console.Writeline. In the mean time I found that if I register MyContext with the Autofac ExternallyOwned()  option the problem is fixed. No idea why  Autofac doesn't handle the dispose itself.

Comment: This might offer some insight: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ExternallyOwned seems to do the trick.

```
    builder.Register(ctx => new MyContext(
        Assembly.Load("TestEFThreads"),
        dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options)).ExternallyOwned();
```

[image: Normal memory consumption]